# Undefined Offset: 0 in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I sen a request this page , I got an error like this

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Filename: models/mproduk.php

Line Number: 116
```

This is my controller

```
public function update($id=''){
        $data = array(); 
        $data['size'] = $this->msize->tampil();

        $data['eta']=$this->mproduk->berapakah_stoknya($id);
        $data['cats']   = $this->mkategori->tampil();
        $data['prd']    = $this->mproduk->get_produk_detail($id);
        $data['human']    = $this->mhuman->tampil();

        $html = array();
        $html['header']     = $this->load->view('secuser/header',null,true);
        $html['kiri']       = $this->load->view('secuser/kiri',null,true);
        $html['content']    = $this->load->view('secuser/product/update',$data,true);
        $this->load->view('secuser/template',$html);
    }
```

This is my model

```
public function berapakah_stoknya($kodepro){  
        $this->load->model('msize');
        $hahaha=$this->msize->tampil();

        foreach($hahaha as $wkwkwkw){
            $apa= $wkwkwkw['id'];
            $sql= "select  ukr_$apa from produk where kodeproduk = '".$kodepro. "'";
            $ggg= $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();    
            $return[]=array('stok'=>$ggg[0]["ukr_$apa"],'ukuran'=>$wkwkwkw['ukuran_produk'],'id_'=>$apa);
        }
        return $return;
    }
```

If I use **error_reporting(0)** the page will be looping and show to be some page

How can i fix this error?

Comment: What is in this array?? `$kodepro`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DB query retrieves no results and therefore `$ggg` is empty and has no `0` index.

Change your model to check if any results were found. If found, add to `$return` array.

```
public function berapakah_stoknya($kodepro){  
    $this->load->model('msize');
    $hahaha = $this->msize->tampil();
    $return = array();
    foreach($hahaha as $wkwkwkw){
        $apa= $wkwkwkw['id'];
        $sql= "select  ukr_$apa from produk where kodeproduk = '".$kodepro. "'";
        $ggg= $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();

        if(count($ggg)>0){
          $return[]=array('stok'=>$ggg[0]["ukr_$apa"],'ukuran'=>$wkwkwkw['ukuran_produk'],'id_'=>$apa);
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

It seems your are expectin to retrieve only one row. So you could use [`row_array`](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html?highlight=result_array#CI_DB_result::row_array).

```
public function berapakah_stoknya($kodepro){  
    $this->load->model('msize');
    $hahaha = $this->msize->tampil();
    $return = array();
    foreach($hahaha as $wkwkwkw){
        $apa= $wkwkwkw['id'];
        $sql= "select  ukr_$apa from produk where kodeproduk = '".$kodepro. "'";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
          $ggg = $query->row_array();
          $return[]=array('stok'=>$ggg["ukr_$apa"],'ukuran'=>$wkwkwkw['ukuran_produk'],'id_'=>$apa);
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```